# How works Hibernate @ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I have 3 entities and one entity for linking these three entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {

          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
          private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ABCXref> abcXref = new ArrayList<ABCXref>();

          // getters/setters
}

@Entity
public class B {

          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
          private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ABCXref> abcXref = new ArrayList<ABCXref>();

          // getters/setters
}

@Entity
public class C {

          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
          private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "c", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ABCXref> abcXref = new ArrayList<ABCXref>();

          // getters/setters
}


@Entity
public class ABCXref {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private A a;

    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
    private B b;  

    @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private C c;
}
```

The question is: does all instances of A, B and C share the same list of `ABCXref's`? What if I add new `ABCXref` to `A` instance? Does this `ABCXref` appear in list of `ABCXrefs` of `B` and `C`?

I.e. will this code output  `true`?

```
println(b.getAbcXref().size()); //0
c.getAbcXref().add(new ABCXref(a, b, c)); 
println(b.getAbcXref().size() == 1) //is `true` or `false`?
```